# Using sed to collect pattern lines and its following lines until another pattern is collected

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to produce a certain output from a file like so

```
>Good_Description1
information
information
information
>BadDescription1
information
information
information
>Good_Description2
information
information
information
```

I would like to produce:

```
>Good_Description1
information
information
information
>Good_Description2
information
information
information
```

How would you go about doing this?

-Thanks

Comment: Your samples are very static looking. Will the number of lines for Good/Bad descriptions change? Will the actual text of Good and Bad (titles) change? Will the text of 'information' for both types change? Maybe you can update your sample data to reflect the range of variation you expect to find in your data OR indicate that the data will really be this static (allowing of course that 'information' (etc) are place holders). The down vote (not from me) is that you should really show some attempt to solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: So you only want the 1st and 3rd blocks of text printed? You get the idea - you haven't told us the criteria you want to use to transform the input to the output yet, you've just shown us 2 stacks of bricks and said you want one to become the other. You did get a downvote and a close-as-too-broad vote from me which I'll retract if/when you clean up your question.

Comment: I think the title says what he wants to achieve.

Comment: @karakfa No it doesn't, you just think it does because you're making assumptions about what it means. Does the OP want to search for a regexp or a string? Does he want a complete or partial match? Does `>foo_Good_Description_bar` mark the start of a block? Are Good_Description1 and 2 two separate values or 2 occurrences of one value? Is he looking for 2 hard-coded values or the first line from the first block then subsequent occurrences of that same string? Is `>BadDescription1` a value we can test (as you assumed in your answer) or just anything that's not `>GoodDescriptionX`? etc., etc....

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^>Good_Des/{p=1} /^>BadDes/{p=0} p' file

>Good_Description1
information
information
information
>Good_Description2
information
information
information
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/>/h;G;/>Good_Description/P;d' file
```

Store the description in the hold space and append it to each line. If the line contains `>Good_Description` then print the first line only.